# Using static Ffmpeg .exe with libavformat linked in project

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libavformat

I'm trying to do something like the following example:

https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/0.6/output-example_8c-source.html

If you want to do this you have to include libavformat in your project. Until now I've been working with the command line tool from ffmpeg with which you don't have to include anything.

At this point I seem to need the libavformat if I want to properly describe the frames I'm going to write to the output file.

Is it possible to use libavformat as a seperate .lib in my project without having to include everything ffmpeg delivers, and can I then still use the .exe from ffmpeg? This should be possible because otherwise there would be some license issues with some codecs.

The user of my project needs to be able to change the ffmpeg .exe to be able to choose different codecs who were not supplied by me.

Comment: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Using%20libav* may be useful

Comment: I don't think I can use the libav libraries directly because I can't change which ffmpeg version it needs to use. (I need to take care of the licenses on the encoders) I have an .exe of ffmpeg though. I don't know if I can use that one if I only include the libav library in my project

Comment: for reference, what about "properly describing frames" can you not do on the command line here?

Comment: Well I can't find how to do that. If I could find that all problems should be solved